# Iterate Two Pandas Dataframes only keeping rows if date is newer

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

What would be the fastest way to iterate through two dataframes based on matching ID column but build a new dict with the rows from DF1 that have a later date than DF2.

```
df1
ID  date
1   1/1/2020
2   1/1/2021
3   1/1/2020

df2
ID  date
1   1/1/2020
2   1/1/2020
3   1/1/2020

new DF1
ID  date
2   1/1/2021

for index1,row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2,row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if row1['ID'] == row2['ID'] and row1['last_edited_date'] > row2['last_edited_date']:
            newdict = row1.to_dict()
```

Comment: Are the dates in `df2` always newer than those in `df1`?

Comment: Df1 dates will be the newer date if there is one.

Comment: Are your dates actually in that format (d/m/y?), or are they actual dates?

Comment: They are actual dates. I just typed that out for an example

Comment: No, there could be some in df1 and not in df2 and vice versa. but i just want to keep df1 rows

Comment: Your sample data has newer dates in `df2`, not `df1`.

Comment: I updated it, I set them up backwards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another possible solution:

```
# df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date'])
# df2['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['date'])

df1.set_index('ID', inplace=True)
df2.set_index('ID', inplace=True)

df2[df1['date'].lt(df2['date'])].reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   ID       date
0   2 2021-01-01
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a classical [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html), then filter the rows :

```
# uncomment in case of non parsed dates
# df1["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df1["date"])
# df2["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df2["date"])
​
out = (
    df1.merge(df2, on="ID", suffixes=("_", ""))
        .query("date > date_")[df1.columns]
        .assign(date= lambda x: x["date"].dt.strftime("%#m/%#d/%Y")) #optional ?
        # .to_dict("list") #uncomment in case you need a dictionary
)
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   ID      date
1   2  1/1/2021
```

Comment: why not a merge and then filter?

Comment: Yes, I was about to post a simple merge approach and I also wonder if a [`condtionnal_join`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join) would be suitable here. I updated my answer!

Comment: what is the .assign part for? just for setting the date structure? I tried this without that line and it seems to work great.

Comment: Yes I've marked this chain/line with a comment (`#optional`) because I wasn't sure of your expected output. It is used to *re-assign* the column `date` and format it with a specific string format `1/1/2021`. Without this chain, you'll get a timestamp: `2021-01-01`